# Разбор предложения и причастный оборот

Tags: причастия, причастный-оборот

есть предложение:
"Орудия охоты - огнестрельное, пневматическое, охотничье метательное стрелковое и холодное оружие, отнесенное к охотничьему оружию в соответствии с Федеральным законом от 13 декабря 1996 года N 150-ФЗ "Об оружии" (далее - Федеральный закон "Об оружии"), а также боеприпасы, метаемые снаряды к охотничьему метательному стрелковому оружию, капканы и другие устройства, приборы, оборудование, используемые при осуществлении охоты."

Вопросы:

1. Причастный оборот "используемые при осуществлении охоты" относится к "..и другие устройства, приборы, оборудование.." или ко всему перечисленному т.е.  "оружие, боеприпасы, снаряды ,капканы и другие устройства, приборы, оборудование..."? Почему?
2. Почему здесь используется страдательное причастие (используемые), а не действительное (использующиеся)?

Comment: Такой тип причастий характерен для делового стиля.

Comment: Это понятно, я бы сказал это юридический стиль, так как предложение взято из подзаконного акта РФ. Проблема именно в понимании к какому подлежащему используется причастный оборот. Т.к. в зависимости от понимания суть закона очень сильно меняется.

Comment: Официально-деловой, по классификации. Следует обратить внимание на тавтологию в: *метаемые снаряды к **охотничьему** метательному стрелковому оружию, используемые при осуществлении **охоты***. Ну и обороты относятся к последнему сегменту. Второй начинается с "а также", а третий — с "другие". Почему суть очень сильно меняется?

Comment: Ну дело в том, что "охотничье метательное стрелковое оружие" - это отдельный вид оружия имеющий свое собственное определение в НПА, при этом в отдельном НПА есть определение что такое "охота" (деятельность, связанная с поиском, выслеживанием, преследованием охотничьих ресурсов, их добычей, первичной переработкой и транспортировкой). Сильно меняется, потому что если причастный оборот относится и к оружию тоже, то тогда, нахождение оружия в чехле, скажем в автомобиле,  не будет считаться охотой и как следствие не нарушает отдельных правил охоты.

Comment: Перевозка охотничьего оружия чисто логически к охоте не относится. Она может быть и для других целей. Относится уже его применение. Но орудия охоты — они, как говорится, и в Африке орудия охоты. Что с ними делаешь, на это не влияет. Поэтому не понимаю проблему.

Comment: Логически не относится, только в ФЗ об охоте есть статья 57 п.2: "к охоте приравнивается нахождение в охотничьих угодьях физических лиц с орудиями охоты и (или) продукцией охоты, собаками охотничьих пород, ловчими птицами". Поэтому получается, что т.к. охота = находждения в угодьях с орудиями охоты, а орудием охоты является охотничье ружье, даже в чехле. То просто нахождения в охотугодьях с зачехленным оружием в машине без разрешения на охоту является нарушением правил охоты.

Comment: Ну это, чтобы не увиливали. А то поймают, а они скажут, что просто с ружьями гуляют.

Comment: Орудием охоты является даже охотничье ружьё, висящее на стене. Никакой роли не играет, где оно находится. Это просто по части классификации.

Comment: Проблема в том что закон в таком виде ограничивает права на передвижение с оружием в охотничьих угодьях. При этом охотничьи угодья это не только лес далеко за городом. По факту, даже общедоступные дороги и трассы являются частью охотничьих угодий. Сейчас охотничье оружие можно использовать не только для охоты, но так же на стрельбище. И стрельбища эти, как правило, находятся за пределами населенных пунктов. На практике, уже сейчас существует целая гора судебных административных дел не впользу законопослушных владельцев охотничьего оружия.

Comment: Как это общедоступные дороги и трассы? Есть территории, на которых находятся животные. И естественно, что с оружием туда будут ехать для охоты, а не просто так. Поэтому не надо проезжать возле таких территорий с оружием. А тем более через них.

Answer (score 0):

**1.**
Отнесение причастного оборота к однородным членам происходит следующим образом:

Если у слов разное число или род, то отнесение оборота очевидно, – например, в предложении: ‟Я взял пистолет и патроны, купленные очень давно” – очевидно, что к чему относится.

Если все однородные во множественном числе, то отнесение оборота определяется по смыслу. Например, такое предложение: ‟Я взял пистолеты и ножи, заточенные по особой технике” – понятно, что пистолеты нельзя заточить.

В вашем предложении по смыслу понятно, что оборот ‟используемые для охоты” относится только к ‟другие устройства, приборы, оборудование”, а не к однородным перед союзом ‟и” (капканы и другие устройства, используемые для охоты).

**2.** Есть слово ‟использовать”, и есть слово ‟использоваться”, в вашем предложении подходит как страдательное причастие слова ‟использовать” – ‟используемые”, так и активное причастие слова ‟использоваться” – ‟использующиеся”. Оба слова одинаково подходят в этом предложении. Я не понимаю, что вас не устраивает.